# How do you add a description text in Storybook for Vue?

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I am trying to find information on how to create some text to describe a component as shown in this screen shot from https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/writing-docs/doc-blocks

[image: screenshot]

I've checked [Component Story Format](https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/api/csf) and I didn't find the information there, they only had `title`, `component`, `decorators` and `parameters`.  There's nothing I can find in the generated example either.

Comment: I *think* this is accomplished with the [docs addon](https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/writing-docs/introduction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @david weldon's comment.  There's a small blurb on [how to document components](https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/writing-docs/introduction) (emphasis mine)

> If you're including Storybook in your project for the first time, we provide you with DocsPage, a documentation template that lists all the stories for a component and associated metadata. It infers metadata values based on source code, types and **JSDoc comments**. If you need, you can customize this page to create your own custom template.

So I tried

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
/**
 * This is a test.
 */
export default defineComponent({
  setup(props) {
    const handleClick = () => {};
    const handleMouseOver = () => {};
    return {
      handleClick,
      handleMouseOver,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

And it does appear
[image]

Comment: How to achieve that when using the new `script setup` syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to add a description to Storybook stories is to use the `parameters` object

```
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent.tsx';

const meta = {
  title: 'Features/MyComponent',
  component: MyComponent,
  parameters: {
    layout: 'centered',
  },
  tags: ['autodocs'],
} satisfies Meta<typeof MyComponent>;

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;

export const prodEnv: Story = {
  args: {
    stage: 'prod',
  },
  parameters: { // <-----------
    docs: {
      description: {
        story: 'Should not render anything in production environment',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

This will result in this output:
[image]